# why the different parceable get instantiated when getParcelable is on different one

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, parcelable

in android having some parcelable classes

```
@Parcelize
class ParcelableClassA(private val member: Int) : IAParcelable {
    init {
        Log.e("+++", "+++ ParcelableClassA::init{}, this: $this")
    }

@Parcelize
class ParcelableClassB(private val member: String) : IBParcelable {
    init {
        Log.e("+++", "+++ ParcelableClassB::init{}, this: $this")
    }
```

in some where it is instantiated and put in a bundle for an activity's creation.

```
Intent(context, TheActivity::class.java).apply {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelable(EXTRAS_CLASS_A, ParcelableClassA(1))
    bundle.putParcelable(EXTRAS_CLASS_B, ParcelableClassB("B")
...
    putExtras(bundle)

    context.startActivity(this)
}
```

in the activity class:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val classA = intent.extras?.getParcelable(EXTRAS_CLASS_A) as? IAParcelable
        val classB = intent.extras?.getParcelable(EXTRAS_CLASS_B) as? IBParcelable

}
```

was expect there would be only one printout `"+++ ParcelableClassA::init{}, this: $this"`
but actually see two instances of the ParcelableClassA are created, one at the

```
intent.extras?.getParcelable(EXTRAS_CLASS_A)
```

and the other also happened when the

```
intent.extras?.getParcelable(EXTRAS_CLASS_B)
```

is called. So both ParcelableClassA::init{}, and ParcelableClassB::init{} are called twice.

and if there are more data put in the extra, the more ParcelableClassA's instantiation is called, which are just waste.

Is this expected behvior or the way it is done here is not correct?

**update:**
seems in the **BaseBundle**'s, if in the unparcel() and the mParcelledData is not null it will have this behavior. But not sure why it happens.
if debug it step by step seems mParcelledData is always null and do not have this problem, but if just run it it will show this problem.

```
void unparcel() {
        synchronized (this) {
            final Parcel source = mParcelledData;
            if (source != null) {
                initializeFromParcelLocked(source, /*recycleParcel=*/ true, mParcelledByNative);
            } else {
                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "unparcel "
                            + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))
                            + ": no parcelled data");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like the use of intent.extra? caused the problem.

if change to

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var bundle  = intent.extras

        val classA = bundle?.getParcelable(EXTRAS_CLASS_A) as? IAParcelable
        val classB = bundle?.getParcelable(EXTRAS_CLASS_B) as? IBParcelable

}
```

seems dont see the dups.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Android framework. What version of Android were you testing this on? Did you check on multiple devices running different versions of Android?

Comment: running on api 29 emulator. the kotlin intent.extras may return a new Bundle(mExtras), while using the  `bundle  = intent.extras`, seems the `initializeFromParcelLocked()` in the `unparcel()` will clear the `mParcelledData` so the dup stops. Not sure if this true tho, since if step in the debug it does not have the problem./

Comment: Normally the `Bundle` is unparceled only once. It is a lazy initialization so it happens as soon as there is a reference to the contents of the `Bundle`.